n-input component of naive UI
i'm trying use n-input component of naive ui for develop web app.
And I need to add "text-overflow: ellipsis" style for it.
This is not working:
<n-input style="text-overflow: ellipsis"/>

The result input on page not content style prop text-overflow.
Accoding naive ui docs n-input not support ellipsis
And I can not use special component n-ellipsis.
Please, I need an advise to solve it.
Thanks

I think you can use input-props to bind props (style) directly to the <input />
<n-input 
    :inputProps="{
      style: {
        text-overflow: ellipsis,
        white-space: nowrap
      }
    }"
/>

The input should be ellipsis when not in focus
